# How can I make a progress complete show in a JTextArea while running code that's figuring out what to display in that JTextArea?

Tags: java, jtextarea, invoke, progress, swingutilities

I don't know if this is possible.  I'm making a lottery application, and I'm trying to use as few GUI components as possible.  So I have a JTextArea that is supposed to show the following message (for example):

"Calculating...55.4%"

When I print it to console, it shows just fine, but it won't print it to the JTextArea.  I tried to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater but that's not working either.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < daysBetween; x++)
    {
      completion = "Calculating..." + df.format((100 * (x + 1)) / daysBetween) + "%";
      if (!textArea.getText().equals(completion))
      {
        textArea.setText(completion);
      }
      /*
      Here I have a lot of irrelevant code that compares your tickets to the winning tickets and counts your winnings and other statistics...
      */
    }

    ticketReport += "Computation time: " + getElapsedTime(start, System.nanoTime());
    ticketReport += "\nEnd date: " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
    ticketReport += "\nTotal # of tickets purchased: " + numOfTicketsPurchased;
    /*
    etc. with filling out the ticket report
    */
    textArea.setText(ticketReport);
```

As you can guess, I want the JTextArea to update as I set the text of the textArea in the for loop above.  It does not update the JTextArea until the end of the method, which is the very bottom when I set the text area to show the ticket report.

[image: Lottery Fever application]

MY END GOAL:  I want to eventually turn this into an Android phone application, so that's why I don't want to use any pop-ups or anything.

Comment: A Swing GUI is event driven.  Console code has to be reworked to fit in the event driven model.  You are probably doing the calculating on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which blocks the GUI from updating.  Good luck converting from a Swing GUI to the Android GUI.  You better be using a [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - I'm mainly trying to get the inner workings complete so I can transfer that over to the Android application.  I know with the Android app I'll have to make an entirely new GUI.  I don't have much experience with Android apps, so not sure how I'll approach it.  Not sure if I should do an Activity or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original SwingWorker approach made it where it showed the completion percentage status in the JTextArea.  I added an option to cancel the operation, and when I attempted to cancel, the "thread" (SwingWorker) would not cancel.  When I cancel and restart, it would stack constantly.  Each successive starting while the other was going would cause the calculations to go slower and slower, and then give incorrect information.

The way I did it this second time solved the original problem and this new problem.  I created a new private class that extends Thread, overran its run() method, and inserted the code to be executed in the thread in that method.  I noticed any method to stop the thread was deprecated because of potential issues, so I created a boolean to be set when the user requests to stop the thread, and inside the thread it periodically reads the value of the boolean, then exits when it equals to true.

The way I start the thread is by re-initializing the object BackgroundCalc and calling its start() method.

```
  private class BackgroundCalc extends Thread
  {
    public void run()
    {
      /*
      initializing stuff here
      */
      for (int x = 0; x < daysBetween; x++)
      {
        progress = (100 * (x + 1)) / daysBetween;
        if (destroyCalcThread) return;
        /*
        background calculations here
        */
      }
      /*
      finish up thread here
      */
    }
  }
```

I'm a little inexperienced with threads, so hopefully my struggle here and the way I explained it will help someone else who's inexperienced with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

/*
EDIT:  This temporarily solved the problem, but I ran into another problem.  Now when I attempted to cancel the SwingWorker by calling its cancel method with parameter true, it would not cancel.  Please see my other answer for the way I solved this.
*/

I figured it out.  The method above I put inside a SwingWorker, as follows:

```
      SwingWorker<Void, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>()
      {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
          //method here
        }
      }
```

Inside that method, I called setProgress method with parameter "(100 * (x + 1)) / daysBetween" to show the correct % completion.  Then after that, I added this:

```
      sw.execute();
      sw.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0)
        {
          textArea.setText("Calculating..." + sw.getProgress() + "%");
          if (sw.getProgress() == 100)
            textArea.setText(ticketReport);
        }
      });
```

It shows percentages as whole numbers rather than the #.## I originally wanted, but I can change very easily if I wanted to.